# How to intercept the call to constructor of class Hash?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I want to execute a function when a constructor of class Hash is called or when a Hash object is initialized. I have implemented my objective using

```
class Hash
  def initialize
    p "Constructor call"
  end
end
```

The code above works fine when a Hash object is initialized as follows:

```
a = Hash.new(:a1 => "Hi")
```

However, when I use the following code:

```
a = {:a1 => "Hi"}
```

Then, it fails or the constructor is not called. So, how to intercept the call made in the second code snippet?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't in MRI, but could probably manage something in Rubinius / JRuby.

Comment: Correct. There are certain things you can't override. At least "!" became overridable in 1.9, allowing you to override negation (!object)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, just like in almost every other language, you cannot override literals in Ruby. You'll have to use one of the few languages that allow this, like [Ioke](http://Ioke.Org/):

```
cell(:{}) = method(+x, "Literal {} called with #{x inspect}" println)

{ :a1 => "Hi" }
;; Literal {} called with [:a1 => "Hi"]
```

(In fact, Ioke is the *only* language I can think of right now which allows literal overloading / overriding. I suppose Ioke's cousin [Seph](http://Seph-Lang.Org/) will support it, and a couple of years of ago there was some discussion about allowing it in [Newspeak](http://NewspeakLanguage.Org/), but that's about it.)