# Is there a way to overwrite the `{ }` object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activesupport

I'm trying to make all Hashes in my program be ActiveSupport::OrderedHash.

I can override the Hash.new constructor by `::Hash = ActiveSupport::OrderedHash` but `{}.class` is still hash.

`def {}` gives me a syntax error.

It was recommended that this is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12989011), but I don't think that is the case. My question isn't about subclassing Hash, it's about overwriting the default `{ }` => Hash constructor.

Comment: No. It's not an object, it's a syntax. It's like asking *"can I overwrite `if`"*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I override the \[\]= method when subclassing a ruby hash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12989011/how-can-i-override-the-method-when-subclassing-a-ruby-hash)

Comment: Hashes in ruby are ordered since 1.9, so what is the point of using ActiveSupport::OrderedHash?

Comment: @pleaner  Your Question is _as same as_  could we override **def ()**. But we can't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hash literal `{}` is hard-coded in Ruby, and you cannot change it. `{}` will become a `Hash`. However, since Ruby's class can be modified, you can remove all unnecessary methods, constants, variables from `Hash`, and copy everything that is in `ActiveSupport::OrderedHash` into `Hash`.

Answer (score 2):

There are only very few languages which allow you to overload literals (I only know of two: [Ioke](http://ioke.org/) and [Seph](http://seph-lang.org/)). Ruby is not one of them.

See also [overloading Ruby's `[…]` Array creation shorthand](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8119962/2988), [Which method is invoked by `[…]` in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12586979/2988), and [How to intercept the call to constructor of class `Hash`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5359397/2988).